# Docker port expose issue, Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, go, networking

I am trying to run a Go app binary in a docker container. The app has some gRPC request being listen and server on:

```
http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8081", nil)
```

In my docker-compose.yaml. I have a service of the app mapped to 8081:

```
  golangAPP:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/golangAPP/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - setup
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
```

After `docker-compose up` I can see the verbose that the app is being served.

But I still cannot reach it. `curl -X OPTIONS http://localhost:8081` return

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

If I run the binary locally without docker, then I can send request to the app.

Any suggestion? I did some googling and some point to firewall issue. But I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Use this: `http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)`

Comment: @BurakSerdar That is it. Thank you ! Please submit your answer. And I will much appreciate if you can explain why as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do:

```
http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8081", nil)
```

this will listen to connections from the loopback interface. When running within a container, this will only accept connections coming from within that container (or if you're running this in a k8s pod, within the same pod). So:

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
```

This will accept both loopback and external connections (external to the container).